# Triggering onchange event in a for-loop only runs one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a page that creates dropdown objects dinamically with an associated event.

The onchange event works great for all objects when is run by the user.
My issue is when I invoke the "onchange" programmatically. It only runs one time. This is how I'm doing that:

```
for (i = 0; i < me.datasource.DocLines.length; i++) {
    data = me.datasource.DocLines[i];
    x = $('#subproduct_' + data.Code);
    x.val(data.Value);
    x.change();
}
```

I'm doing this programmatically because I'm binding the dropdown values from a database and I need to recreate the calculations to show the calculated values to the user.

The cycle only runs one time. After being triggered the onchange event, the code execution exits the cycle and I don't know why. 
I've already checked the me.datasource.DocLines.length which is always > 1, which means that the cycle should run at least two times.

Any clue on why this is happening?

edit
More info:

this is how I associated a function to the dropdown controls

```
     for (i = 0; i < dbdata.length; i++) {
            if ((dbdata[i].Provider) == "False") { //create dropdownboxes events 
                if ((dbdata[i].Dimension) != "True") {

                    $('#subproduct_' + dbdata[i].Code).change({
                        me: me
                    }, doSomething);
                }
           }
     }
    //....
```

This "doSomething" only runs one time. I can check that by setting a breakpoint to it.

Comment: No error on the console ?? How are you sure that is the `change()` which breaks the loop ?

Comment: no errors on the console. I set a breakpoint in the first line of the for-loop ( data = me.datasource.DocLines[i];) and the code doesn't stop there. Also, I can check by the value that I want to calculate that it has only run one time(it's a totalizer). Also, I've set up a breakpoint in the function that is in the "onchange" event and it would only stop there one time.

Comment: Those are important information. Did you tried to run all change events *after* the loop at once ?

Comment: Let me correct what i said: the function inside of the event never runs. Making a watch to the "x", shows all the values that are inside of the dropdowbox but no onchange function associated.
This function was created in run-time.

Comment: And yes, I tried to run the onchange in a separate for-loop, @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: Try `x.trigger("change");`

Comment: Same thing. It only runs for the first time.
Again, I've made a mistake regarding my last comment. The "doSomething" function present in the onchange event only runs one time.
I was trying to see if "x.change;" did someting but, ofcourse, it didn't. Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the "i" iterator to a new variable, my problem was solved. There was also a "i" variable being used in the "doSomething" function.

Comment: Or maybe declaring `i` in the loop scope - avoiding the global scope - would achieve, e.g.: `for (var i = 0...`